# HLS Streaming: Multiple Audio Alternatives in Video Stream

Tags: ios, audio, video, http-live-streaming

I have a problem with a certain HLS streaming setup. So far, my setup is that I'm using a video rendition of the stream which contains all the different audio alternatives as stream in the name `.mp4`. According to the [specs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-16#section-4.3.4.1), this should be possible by setting up my HLS master manifest like so:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="aac",CODECS="mp4a.40.5",LANGUAGE="deu",NAME="Deutsch",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="aac",CODECS="mp4a.40.5",LANGUAGE="spa",NAME="Español",DEFAULT=NO
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="aac",CODECS="mp4a.40.5",LANGUAGE="eng",NAME="English",DEFAULT=NO

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1391346,RESOLUTION=1022x574,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.5",AUDIO="aac"
0009_orig/manifest.m3u8
```

However, testing this on an iPad, the video player offered me the different languages, but after choosing them, the player **did not** actually switch the language.

My guess is that the player is not able to actually find the corresponding track in the original stream. Is this even possible? Can I set this information in the manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: The answer below applies to the [version 3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-06) of the protocol. The IETF draft you linked is for [version 7](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-16). If the device supports version 7 you may be able to use a muxed media file although I haven't tried it yet. Use `#EXT-X-VERSION:7` instead.

According to [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/AboutHTTPLiveStreaming/about/about.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013978-CH3-SW17):

> **Alternate Audio and Video Renditions**

> The audio tracks contain **unmuxed** (signals have not been combined) audio
> segments. The master playlist file controls the playback.

I take it this means you *have* to provide the URI for a single audio stream:

```
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="aac",NAME="Deutsch", \
      DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,LANGUAGE="de", \
      URI="main/german-audio.m3u8"
```

Comment: No it only means that my audio playlists must only contain a single audio stream. It doesn't say anything about the audio being part of the video stream.

Comment: True, but it doesn't mention the opposite at all. And all their [examples](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2288/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012238-CH1-ALTERNATE_MEDIA) are using the URI.

Comment: Yeah I guess that behaviour is not really specified and I have to deal with that. Thank you.

Comment: Wait, I have an idea. Maybe this is not supported in `#EXT-X-VERSION:3` and only in newer versions. I'll have to dig the info or try.